# How to prevent C++Builder from writing full paths in .cbproj files?

Tags: c++builder

C++Builder (pick any version; the latest we've tried is 10.3.3) insists on writing full paths into the `.cbproj` files it creates, particularly on some of the `ILINK...` properties. For example:

```xml
<ILINK_LibraryPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\lib\win64\release\;C:\Users\dclark\svst\Build64\;$(ILINK_LibraryPath)</ILINK_LibraryPath>
```

We got around this before by making sure everyone had the same folder structure, but that isn't practical anymore.  Is there a way to make C++Builder write only relative paths? Or is the only solution to edit the files directly?

Comment: AFAIK, you have to edit the files manually.

Comment: Write a program to modify the files after... Or replace C++Builder... Or intercept its mechanism for finding absolute paths... (You can hit it downstream, where it's at, or upstream)

Comment: Could you show an example of intercepting that mechanism?  I've never seen it done